# My two monitors are not working anymore

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors, one connected to the NVidia GPU and the other connected to the mother board. They worked well, but suddenly the one connected to the mother board only shows

```
/dev/sda2: 644138/61022208 files, 6400771/244059136,
```

and in the settings, the second monitor doesn't appear.